# Google Search Console: ID mising for breadcrumbs?

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

I have gotten a large numner of errors in the console this morning telling me that none of my breadcrumbs contain an ID. This is true, but it has never been required before. If I add an ID property and try to validate using the structured data validator it says that ID is not a supported field.

I checked the [Google documentation for breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) and if you check the markup examples they have given, none of them contain an ID either. The Schema.org spec doesnt show ID, Google's docs dont show ID support and Google's own structured data testing tool says ID is both unsupported and supported. What is the issue here? Does anyone have an example of how Google want us to implement this?

Comment: Out of interest, what do you mean with "Google's own structured data testing tool says ID is both unsupported and supported"?

Comment: without to see your code it is not possible to help you

Comment: Google examples shows a simplified form. Directly entering in a URL for the item is implying it is a thing with the id of the URL. I don't see the tools complaining when it is done that way.